# iOS keep my app running in background constantly

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to be able to do these few things:

1. Run my app on phone startup
2. Keep it running in the background all the time
3. No UI is needed - this is a statistics app so it will gather all the data it needs and the user should not be bothered with anything.

Are these things possible?

Comment: "Are these things possible?" I honestly hope the answer is a resounding "no" ;-) This is what spyware does, isn't it?

Comment: Become an Android developer and you can do these kinds of malicious things without any review or approval process by the marketplace.  I can't see how an app like this would benefit the user at all.  Apple wouldn't approve an app that does nothing for the user, but Google would.

Comment: Yes my app is not spyware and I have versions for Android and Blackberry and I was curious if I can make an iOS version but I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really. Setting aside jailbreaking and the universe of things that aren't Apple-approved, running in the background full-time is explicitly banned on iOS. Similarly, you can't sell an app on the App Store that doesn't have a user interface, and you can't set apps to run on start up.